# What's wrong with this Jinja template when using {% elif %}

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following **Jinja** template:

```
01. {% if new_data_set_created is defined %}
02.     {% if new_data_set_created == True %}
03.         The new image data set <strong>{{ form_data["data_set_name"] }}</strong> has been created.
04.         {% set form_data = {"data_set_name": "", "client": "", "project": ""} %}
05.     {% else %}
06.         The new image data set <strong>{{ form_data["data_set_name"] }}</strong> could not be created.<br />
07.     {% endif %}
08. {% elif deleted_data_set is defined %}
09.    The image data set <strong>{{ deleted_data_set }}</strong> has been deleted from DB and from disk.
10.    {% set form_data = {"data_set_name": "", "client": "", "project": ""} %}
11. {% else %}
12.     {% set form_data = {"data_set_name": "", "client": "", "project": ""} %}
13. {% endif %}
```

However, when rendering this template via **Flask** I get the error message that `form_data` in line 3 of this code section is undefined (which is not the case, I double-checked that):

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form_data' is undefined
```

Now when I remove the `elif` block from that code section above (i.e. lines 8-10) then the very same template does work again and line 3 does not lead to an error any more.

I am calling this template like so:

```
return render_template(
    "image-data-sets.html",
    new_data_set_created=True,
    form_data=request.form,
    data_sets=ImageDataSet.query.all(),
    clients=clients,
)
```

I double-checked that `request.form` (and thus `form_data` within the template) is not `None`. And as said, I don't make any changes to this call, I just remove those lines from the template and then it's working.

So my question: Why does removing the `elif` block fix this issue, and why is this error raised in the first place? What's wrong with my `if-elif-else-endif` block?

Comment: What's this is doing `form_data=request.form`? Can you post the whole function code?

Comment: It seems to be a thing with Jinja, [see here](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/1253#issuecomment-653158275).